# c# nothing printed though there are many data

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, printing

I have a grid view and I want to print it.

This is my code:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) {
            int rowCounter = 0;
            int z = 0;
            StringFormat str = new StringFormat();
            str.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            str.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            str.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;

            int width = 500 / (GridView.Columns.Count - 2);
            int realwidth = 100;
            int height = 40;

            int realheight = 100;

            for (z = 0; z < GridView.Columns.Count - 1; z++)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, realwidth, realheight, width, height);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, realwidth, realheight, width, height);

                e.Graphics.DrawString(GridView.Columns[z].HeaderText, GridView.Font, Brushes.Black, realwidth, realheight);

                realwidth = realwidth + width;
            }

            z = 0;
            realheight = realheight + height;
            while (rowCounter < GridView.Rows.Count)
            {
                realwidth = 100;
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, realwidth, realheight, width, height);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, realwidth, realheight, width, height);

                e.Graphics.DrawString(GridView.Rows[rowCounter].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), GridView.Font, Brushes.Black, realwidth, realheight);
                realwidth = realwidth + width;
            }

            printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }
```

and when the use click on the printing button, I do this:

```
DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.printDocument1.Print();
            }
```

plus in the construction of the form, I initialze the printing variables like this:

```
this.printDocument1 = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            this.printDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
```

my problem that when I click print, I got empty page though the grid view has more than 320 rows

#### Update 1

I am following this tutorial http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWinFormPrintDataGridView-75864c45

#### Update 2

The grid view variable is `GridView`

The code is straightforward I guess

#### Update 3

I added

```
++rowCounter;
realheight = realheight + height;
```

ad the end of the `while` loop and still the same result

Comment: In the Rows-Loop, shouldn't you advance the height? and the rowcounter?

Comment: @TaW I am trying your idea,

Comment: @TaW do you mean adding `++rowCounter; realheight = realheight + height;` at the end of the printing function ?

Comment: I guess so. I didn't check very thoroughly but found the loop a bit strange. actually it shouldn't ever finish but the page(s) shouldn't be all emtpy either, at least the headrs ought to show up..

Comment: @TaW yes at least the header, that is why i am shocking. Plus, i tested adding those two line of code, but still the same result.

Comment: @TaW I made a break point in the first of the printing function but that break point never reached, so the function is not being called right?

Comment: Right. Is the PrintPage event actually hooked up with the printDocument1?

Comment: @TaW no ..... this works for me `printDocument1.PrintPage += printDocument1_PrintPage; // the missing piece` but though i have another problem and will ask about in another thread, type an answer to accept it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as posted has at least three problems:

- In your rows loop you don't advance the rowcounter, which will result in an endless loop.
- You also don't advance your realheight variable, which will in result in overprinting all lines
- since none of this happens your printDocument1_PrintPage event isn't called; you have probably only copied the code from the example and not actually hooked it up with the printDocument1.

Add to the loop's end:

```
rowCounter++;
realheight += height;
```

and in the constructor:

```
this.printDocument1.PrintPage += this.printDocument1_PrintPage;
```

Fixing these problems should at least print out something...